# Removing the title from the title bar and the menu dots

Tags: android, xml, eclipse

How can I remove the title from the title bar and the menu dots?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1aFE.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put below line in activity tag in manifest for removing title bar:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

and remove below code from activity class for removing dots:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        /
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Or one worked, the other didnt, the code
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);
} how shall put it?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
final  ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
```

Comment: package com.as.masa;

import android.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
 
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);
    }
}

Comment: Im new to this, so please help? :)

Comment: i think you wanted to post your first comment to the answer about my post, and not to my post...